# pip update all virtualenv packages based on setup.py

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, flake8

I have a project, which uses `tox` to run various checks on the CI. And I can run it locally. The thing is, when `flake8` gets called on tox, it uses its plugins versions from the setup.py, so in this case - the newest ones (since I don't limit them with `==` or `<=`). I also have flake8 and its plugins (in this case e.g. `wemake-python-styleguide`) installed locally in my virtualenv.

The problem is that some packages are outdated compared to the ones, that get installed in tox environment. And I get different errors locally and on pipeline (I mean I can run tox locally, but it takes longer that just running `flake8` in the terminal).

So my question is: is there a way to update all the packages? I mean I can run `pip install -e "."` or `pip install -e ".[dev,tests]"`, even with `--upgrade` flag, but it still doesn't update  my packages. I checked: tox uses e.g. `wemake-python-styleguide==0.13.1` and in my local virtualenv I've got `wemake-python-styleguide==0.12.5`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to recreate your local virtualenv or tox environment

You can do this with `tox -r`

Note also, newer versions of `tox` have a convenient command to create a local virtualenv (outside of `.tox`) -- `tox --devenv ENVDIR`

For example, if you wanted to make `./venv38` via the settings in `py38` you could invoke the following:

```sh
tox --devenv venv38 -e py38
```

Alternatively, you could use pip to upgrade your packages, but this may leave behind unneeded packages:

```sh
pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager -e .[dev,tests]
```

(disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of `tox` and added that feature -- also the current `flake8` maintainer but it doesn't seem relevant to the question here)